# Unelegant decorate-count-undecorate on data.table cumulative sum

Tags: r, data.table, cumsum

I wish to keep a counter by "description". 
Can the following code be 1-liner:

```
dt[, dummy:=1]
dt[, count:=lapply(.SD,cumsum), by = "description", .SDcols=("dummy")]
dt[, dummy:=NULL]
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a `dummy` column?  WOuldn't `dt[, cum.count:=lapply(.SD,cumsum), by = description, .SDcols=1]` work?  It is better to show a small reproducible example with an expected output rather than just showing some codes.

Comment: Very inelegant indeed. Probably whatever you're trying to do can be accomplished with the `.I` or `.N` functionality of `data.table`.

Comment: arkun, I have tried .SDcols=1 before refering to . simply

Comment: arkun, I have tried .SDcols=1 before refering to stackoverflow. 
It simply sends you to the first column of the table.
You are right about reproducible code would make things clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want:

```
dt[ , count := rowid(description)]
```